# How use copyfiles from electron

Tags: npm, electron

I don't know how I can use the `copyfiles` function.
I want to copy a whole "dist" file (with subfiles) in a "electron" file like

```
copyfiles dist electron
```

The "dist" is the sourcefile and "electron" is the targetFile.
How can I do that?

Comment: the question is unclear. dist/electron are folders or files? do you just need to copy some files from one folder to another during npm build?

Comment: @udalmik The are Folders. I need to copy the whole dist Folder in the electron folder.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if understood your question. If you just need to copy some assets/resources during your NPM build, then you can use one of existing npm modules, e.g. [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles)

So you need to install it as dev dependency

```
npm i copyfiles --save-dev
```

And add corresponding task to your `package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "copy-assets": "copyfiles dist/* electron"
}
```